# jQuery UI and fancybox issue: Jumps to top after open fancybox

Tags: jquery, user-interface, fancybox

I got an issue between jQuery UI accordion and the latest fancybox. After clicking a fancybox linked image in the accordion the script jumps always to the top of my site. The only option I set for accordion is *heightStyle: "content"*. I have no idea where the issue could be.

Comment: you may have set `height` and/or `width` to either the `html` or `body` tags

Comment: What does your link look like? Likely you have an `<a href="#">` without an `onclick` handler that returns false.

Comment: @JFK: Ah yeah you're right. ^^; Thank you! :) Problem fixed and so simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that fancyBox changes the overflow value of the body in order to hide the browser scrollbars. This can actually be done with a helper in Fancybox 2.

```
$('.image').fancybox({
  padding: 0,
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      locked: false
    }
  }
});
```